# AWS Pinpoint Android, "EventRecorder: Unable to successfully deliver events to server"

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, aws-pinpoint

I'm attempting to get AWS Pinpoint to send notifications to my Android app. I have gone through the setup testing instructions here: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/push-notifications

I'm able to get a Pinpoint client device token and send a message with the Pinpoint test messaging console. Once I send the message I get the following stacktrace in my log:

```
2019-04-11 11:56:34.757 8880-9196/com.example E/EventRecorder: Unable to successfully deliver events to server. Events will be saved, error likely recoverable.Cognito Identity not configured
com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Cognito Identity not configured
    at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient.getCredentials(AWSMobileClient.java:352)
    at com.amazonaws.services.pinpoint.AmazonPinpointClient.invoke(AmazonPinpointClient.java:4024)
    at com.amazonaws.services.pinpoint.AmazonPinpointClient.putEvents(AmazonPinpointClient.java:3074)
    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.pinpoint.internal.event.EventRecorder.submitEventsAndEndpoint(EventRecorder.java:366)
    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.pinpoint.internal.event.EventRecorder.submitEventsAndEndpoint(EventRecorder.java:344)
    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.pinpoint.internal.event.EventRecorder.processEvents(EventRecorder.java:315)
    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.pinpoint.internal.event.EventRecorder$1.run(EventRecorder.java:240)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:914)
```

The stacktrace suggests I need "Cognito Identity" for messaging to work, but I don't want that service as I already have user management/authentication process built.

How do I resolve this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by using a physical device instead of the emulator.